# Precision of temperature values when using python-nest

Tags: python, api, precision, temperature, nest-api

I am trying to set up something to plot the data from my new nest learning thermostat (rev 3). I found the [nest-python api package forked and enhanced by jkoelker](https://github.com/jkoelker/python-nest). I want the data to be as precise as possible. I have it reporting data from my own thermostat but the values I get from it are always whole number with a decimal tenth value of zero like "XX.0". For example:

```
$ ./runnest.py
Structure My Home
    Away: home
    Devices:
        Device: Hallway
            Temp: 66.0F
Structure   : My Home
 Postal Code                    : None
 Country                        : US
 num_thermostats                : 1
        Device: Hallway
        Where: Hallway
            Mode       : heat
            HVAC State : off
            Fan        : False
            Fan Timer  : 15
            Temp       : 66.0F
            Humidity   : 30.0%
            Target     : 67.0F
            Eco High   : 76.0F
            Eco Low    : 40.0F
            hvac_emer_heat_state  : False
            online                : True

$
```

I saw from the [documented page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-nest) this comment:

> The utils function use decimal.Decimal to ensure precision.

but I'm unsure how to use this. I've tried using it this way: `nest.utils.decimal.Decimal(device.temperature))` but it still prints a whole number with a point zero (like 68.0 instead of 67.8). I can check the wall unit and pull up the `Settings->Technical Info->Sensors` and see the resolution I want (tenths of a degree Fahrenheit) like 66.4 but when I poll the data using the library it always comes out as something like 66.0 instead.

Is there some way I can adjust the code to get temperature values and measurements with tenths of a degree precision from my nest learning thermostat through the python-nest API?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API documentation](https://developers.nest.com/documentation/cloud/api-thermostat) it's the expected behavior for F:

> ambient_temperature_f:
>   Temperature, measured at the device, in whole degrees Fahrenheit (1°F).

While for Celsius:

> ambient_temperature_c:
>   Temperature, measured at the device, in half degrees Celsius (0.5°C).